# Why am I getting duplicate node labels from Ciw?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a working example:

```py
import ciw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

max_time = 20

# Routing Matrix
R = [[0]*7 for i in range(7)]
R[0][1] = 1
R[1][0] = 1/3
R[1][2] = 1/3
R[1][3] = 1/3
R[2][1] = 1
R[3][1] = 1/2
R[3][5] = 1/2
R[5][3] = 1/3
R[5][4] = 1/3
R[5][6] = 1/3
R[6][5] = 1/2

# Arrival dists
arr_dists = [ciw.dists.Exponential(1/10)] * 3 + [None] * 4


N = ciw.create_network(
    arrival_distributions=arr_dists,
    service_distributions=[ciw.dists.Exponential(1)] * 7,
    routing=R,
    number_of_servers=[1]*7,
    queue_capacities=[1]*7

)

ciw.seed(2018)
Q = ciw.Simulation(N)
Q.simulate_until_max_time(max_time)
slow_df = pd.DataFrame(
        Q.get_all_records()
        )

slow_df.plot.bar(x='node', y='time_blocked'); plt.show()
```

I get this plot, which seems to have duplicate node labels:

[image]

Any yet checking `slow_df.node.apply(type).unique()` gives only `array([<class 'int'>], dtype=object)`, so I am not sure what would make an integer `3` distinct from another since they are value objects.

Similarly:

```py
>>> slow_df.node.unique()
array([3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5])
```

Why am I getting repeat nodes in my plot?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is just expected behaviour of `df.plot.bar`. It assumes that every value of `x` is distinct and will plot it as a separate value. It does not provide any group-then-aggregate functionality.

To quickly plot the stacked values, you could instead use `slow_df.plot.scatter(x='node', y='time_blocked')`.

[image]

Alternatively, a swarmplot could work:

```py
sns.swarmplot(data=slow_df, x='node', y='time_blocked');plt.show()
```

[image]

And I'm sure various other plots might serve the desired purpose.